# HDP2.3 : Call to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;

Tags: hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform

This is little strange but:

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

giving:

```
Call From <hostname> to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

but if i am using : `hadoop fs -ls hdfs://hostname:8020/` , then i am getting proper results.
I am not able to figure out the issue.Using HDP 2.3 with default configuration.
How to make `hadoop fs -ls /` working??

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify fs.defaultFS parameter to hdfs://hostname:8020 either in core-site.xml directly or via Ambari, if you are using it.